# Auto sort for tags

Tags: feature-request, meta

Tiny suggestion, which really isn't that important.

Sort all tags alphabetically when you display them. Always show the red tags first followed by the admin tags, followed by the rest (all sorted alphabetically  ).

The front page on meta looks kind of inconsistent.

Comment: Im not sure that this is meta-meta only, I think it also applies to SO to a lesser degree ...

Comment: What up, are the tags not showing any more on the front page as boxes?