# How is this user causing activity?

Tags: support, question-activity

Sorry for the vague title, I wasn't sure how to ask this question.  There are two active questions on the main page as I write this that have activity attributed to the user [m1ndw0rk](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/147075/m1ndw0rk): [Auto sort for tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8689/auto-sort-for-tags) and [Should credit for an idea in an SO Q or A be given by a link to the user’s page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54848/should-credit-for-an-idea-in-an-so-q-or-a-be-given-by-a-link-to-the-users-page).  There was a third until a few minutes ago when someone edited it: [Alphabetize tags list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2214/alphabetize-tags-list).

As far as I can tell, that user had no connection to any of the three questions.  They were asked at different times by different people, including at least one certifiable Meta celebrity, and I don't see the user in the revision history for any of them.

The user's profile is oddly empty as well.  The lack of personal info could be intentional; I'm not sure which fields are required, if any.  But the user also has only 1 rep and zero questions, answers, votes and badges.  The activity list is blank, too.

Is this user a system puppet like [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) or [Sneakers O'Toole](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10?tab=stats#tab-top), maybe?  (I doubt it; there's no profile message saying so.)  Is this only happening on my machine and I've gone crazy?  (I doubt that too; nobody else in the office is looking at me funny.  Well, any more than usual.)  Did I find an actual bug?  (More likely, I'm missing something obvious, but I'm sure one of you has a helpful cluebat.)

Comment: You can't see it because you're <10k (and nor can I, for that matter, but I saw the actual activity myself), but that user posted several answers and subsequently deleted them. That's what the activity was. Whether it was a test or a berserk user, I don't know, but I already threw up a flag. If it was a real problem and not a test or just normal user activity, it has most likely been solved by now.

Comment: @Grace Note: Probably it was just to bump them. There aren't a lot of options for bumping as a 1-rep user.

Comment: @mmyers I was thinking that at first, but the credit question was entirely out-of-place - it is both a recent question and it is unrelated to the other two. I simply erred to the thought of "must be someone testing something" because there was a recent discussion about whether 1 rep users could delete their own posts or not.

Comment: @Grace Note: You're right, it was likely a test of some kind. The three answers are, respectively: "delete my answer, please!", "adsfasdfsadfasdfasd", and "some answer text".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All three had answers which have now been deleted by the owner.

Adding and then deleting an answer counts as activity so you (or in this case m1ndw0rk) will show up as the last person to be active in that question.

All three answers were meaningless noise.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how many times were each of those deleted and undeleted according to the revision history? Because I think I saw one of them being undeleted at least once or twice.

Comment: @Grace - if they were deleted and undeleted before being deleting again it all happened within the first 5 minutes of them being posted. There are no revisions of those answers.

Comment: Grumble grumble deleted content.  There's ten minutes of my life I'll never see again.

Comment: Huh, you learn something new every day. I figured that rapid delete/undelete would be all tracked... but I guess that too has a window.

Answer (score 19):

It's called ninja-bumping and it is quite frowned upon.  The user posted a gibberish answer and deleted it which causes activity.  It's usually done on forums where someone wants to get the post back to the top without getting flamed for just posting "bump".

Comment: +1 - I like your explanation better than mine ;)

Answer (score 9):

This particular user shall trouble us no longer.

It is possible to bump a question by answering and then deleting your answer as Jason Punyon described.

Please note, however, that this sort of behavior is not considered community friendly, and will be acted on accordingly.